# Why is my Hard drive recognised as removable?

Tags: boot, external-hdd, automount, drive

I have 2 samsung 840s in my computer, one boot and the other expanded storage but Ubuntu recognizes the second as a removable drive but I want them both to be recognised as internal drives, how do I get it to mount as an internal drive?

Comment: I used Gparted and have them both ext4 and primary

Comment: Just add second drive's partition info inside your `/etc/fstab`. You can achieve it's UUID running `blkid` or `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`.

Comment: What do you mean it recognizes the second as removable?

Answer (score 3):

You have to enter your *2nd* hard disk information to `/etc/fstab` file. Then your *2nd* hard disk will be treated by internal hard drive.

Just go for following step:

- First take back up of `/etc/fstab` and unmount all *2nd* HDD partitions

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
  sudo umount /dev/sdb*
  ```
- Execute following command to get your *2nd* HDD **UUID** information that will help you to configure `/etc/fstab` file.

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```

  Search for your 2nd hard disk **UUID** of all partitions. Your *2nd* HDD partitions shouls be displayed like: `/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Backup" UUID="00A0CE7EA0CE7A24" TYPE="ntfs"` and so on. It is just an example but format will be same.
- Now copy the UUID of the partitions of *2nd* HDD which you want to insert in `/etc/fstab` file.
- Now open `/etc/fstab` file and insert entry for your HDD partitions on the last line of `/etc/fstab` file. Take help from previous entry, for format etc:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/fstab
  ```

  When opened your entry would be like this:

  ```
  UUID=<your_UUID_for_2nd HDD partitions> /media/<location_where_you_want_to_mount>             ntfs    errors=remount-ro 0
  ```

  Just an example:

  UUID=00A0CE7EA0CE7A24 /media/Backup               ntfs    errors=remount-ro 0
- Now create location where to mount your *2nd* HDD partitions. Create a folder for each partitions to mount. For example:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/Backup
  ```
- Then execute this command once finished:

  ```
  sudo mount -a
  ```

You can refer this link for further help: [Auto mounting with /etc/fstab](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1635576)
Hope it works for you..

Comment: Just a note: `/media` is the system managed path for auto-mounted drives. I'd better mount my drives under old point, `/mnt`.

Comment: I don't think so, it effects something. It is fairly a convention used by latest versions of Ubuntu. or you can mount any where you want. for example in your `home` directory.

Comment: SSD's need the discard,noatime options too

Comment: This doesn't make it "treated as internal", it makes it mount automatically at boot instead of when you first click on it in the gui.  Having it mounted under /media makes the gui show the icon.

Comment: Does it make any difference.. It will make it as internal also.. Do you bet me?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Ubuntu 16.04 and wanting to do this with a GUI, I found an easy way. (I presume it would be similar for other versions of Ubuntu, but I haven't tested)

1. Start the 'disks' utility.
2. Select your disk
3. Click gears
4. Select 'Edit mount options...'
5. Set to manual, if not already
6. Untick "Show in user interface"

(You can also set the mount point in this dialog)